# Avoiding database deadlock with mutex in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, mutex

I have three console projects .

Main.exe

Secondary1.exe

Secondary2.exe

Now main.exe  calls the secondary1 and secondary2 exes whenever its needed and give them the id of table in database

main exe never stops but secondary1.exe and secondary2.exe stops after their respective update

Main.exe creates multiple instance of secondary1.exe and secondary2.exe

Main.exe also updates database the same table but not a single row , multiple rows .

We are facing a sql server deadlock issue , when multiple exes are trying to update sql servers , one table .

We have been told to use mutex in c# to solve this in the code level.

Any idea how to do it when the resource is the database

Sorry , could not provide any code as I am not able to it over the three totally independent .exes

Also we are using entity framework

Comment: can you update only one row at a time?

Comment: no i cant ., main will update multiple rows , secondary1 and 2 will update  single rows , but there will multiple instances of secondary ones

Comment: if main updates multiple rows and both secondary single rows you would not get deadlocks, so you have something to optimize

Comment: I need a mutex code which works for multiple process , thanks for your advise . will check optimize part too

Comment: why don't you create queue in main app that calls app1 and app2? and manage this in main app? mutex is used to prevent opening second time the same app, not sure you need to abort sub-apps

Comment: We used it , but its a requirement to have mutex to separate it out and not in a  queue

Comment: does you app run sub-app synchronously or async? if async there is no way to do it with mutex

Answer (score 0):

You need interprocess synchronization object and mutex is not really fit for that.
You can use named Semaphore instead. When it's created, it can be used by any proccess in the system (well, it can be tricky with permission, but with luck it will work right away).

Just put the name to semaphore when you creating it:

```
Semaphore _semaphore = new Semaphore(1,1, "MyNamedSemapthoreName");
```

And use it as always:

```
void DoSomeWithDataBase() {
_semaphore.WaitOne();
DoWorkInDB();
_semaphore.Release(); }
```

Comment: "mutex is not really fit for that" - that's not true, it's perfectly fit for that, certainly not less that named semaphore.

Comment: semaphore is not working any way , secondary2.exe is not waiting till the secondary1.exe is finished with that